# terraform variable type error : Attribute must be a whole number

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

The following code throws the error
Error: Attribute must be a whole number, got 1.123456781234567e+15

on main.tf line 56, in resource "databricks_mws_permission_assignment" "ws_usergp":
│   56:   workspace_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.workspace_id

```
resource "databricks_mws_permission_assignment" "ws_usergp" {
  for_each     = data.azuread_group.this
  provider     = databricks.azure_account
  workspace_id = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.workspace_id
  principal_id = databricks_group.dbxgp[each.key].id
  permissions  = ["USER"]
}

output "dbx"{
  value = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.workspace_id
}
```

The output block somehow returns the correct value dbx="1123456781234567"

Not able to assign the value to workspace_id. Anyone who could help on what needs to be done here?

Troubleshooting steps tried

1. Tried passing as a variable of type number, string,any
2. Tried hardcoding the actual value as string and number
3. Upgraded and downgraded the terraform versions to check if the variable type support has changed

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have this problem because you're using the 32-bit version of Terraform & Databricks Terraform provider (most probably on Windows).  There were multiple errors reported for [similar cases](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20Attribute%20must%20be%20a%20whole%20number), and all were caused by the 32-bit versions.

You need to switch to 64-bit version to make it working.